# CSS: shape-outside + translate

Tags: css, transform, mask, shape-outside

When inserting an element with an image as shape-outside mask and translating the position, the mask is not translating, so the mask is not working properly.

The same is happening if transforming a container around. I tried different things but so far no influence to keep the mask matching the image.

Here is an example:
https://codepen.io/honk007/pen/oNpbRaG

Here you can see the wrong position of the mask:
[image]

```
<div class="container">
   <img class="image" alt="" width="400" height="335" src="https://i.ibb.co/5LJkydd/transparent.png" >
</div>
    
.image {
  float: right;
  shape-outside: url(https://i.ibb.co/5LJkydd/transparent.png);
  transform: translateX(200px);
}

.container { 
    display: flow-root;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    max-width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to float your image?
float:right is supposed to just do that, float to the right specifically.
My understanding is that it is quite difficult to float text around a centered or otherwise positioned element using this approach.

Comment: Transforming an element doesn't affect positioning of other elements.

Comment: @AHaworth look at the mask position in console. I added a picture of that.

Comment: Thanks for putting up the screen shot. In that code you have moved the penguin 200px to the right, using a transform. Its newly translated state isn't going to affect other elements around it so the outcome looks correct to me. Could you perhaps describe what you want to achieve without for the moment thinking of a possible technical solution? Currently your question looks more like an observation than a question. Thanks.

Comment: @AHaworth Isn't the shape-outside mask part of the image element and should be at the same translated position? Because of the current behavior, the text is not correctly flowing around the image.

Answer (score 1):

U can use margin to shift your picture instead of transform. You can't use transform for this because a transform will not influence the position of other elements.

```css
.image {
  float: right;
  shape-outside: url(https://i.ibb.co/5LJkydd/transparent.png);
  margin-right:-200px;
}

.container { 
    display: flow-root;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    max-width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class="image" alt="" width="400" height="335" src="https://i.ibb.co/5LJkydd/transparent.png" >
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the example. I need to move the element out of the container for design purposes.

Comment: What are those design purposes? The answer to this question may help in finding an answer.

Comment: I added the mask position error as a purpose. The problem is that the mask is staying in the same position if the element it belongs to gets moved via `translate`.

Comment: I have changed my answer  but it is really hard to understand what exactly you are looking for. If you just want this to work with ```translate``` then there is no solution.

Comment: In this case it would be better to focus on the problem why u need it to be ```translate``` instead of something else like ```left``` or ```margin-right```